# Volume of a paraboloid

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Find the volume between the XY plane and $z=2-x^2-y^2$

So I start with looking only on a the first octant.

I set $x$ and $y$ to $0$ to find where the paraboloid intersects with the z-axis, and I get $z=2$

then I find the function of $y$ by setting $z=0$, $0=2-x^2-y^2\Rightarrow -2+x^2=-y^2\Rightarrow \sqrt{2-x^2}=y$ and finding $x=\sqrt{2}$

So the integral is $\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2-x^2}}\int_{2-x^2-y^2}^{2}dz dy dx$

Is it right?

Comment: It's better use cilindrical coordinates. In this case the region $R$ is $R=\{(r,\theta,z)|0\leq z\leq 2, 0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi, 0\leq r\leq \sqrt{2} \}$.

Comment: To check result:  $ V = \frac12 Base Area * height $

Comment: @Narasimham height is 2? what will be the base area?

Comment: $ \pi ( \sqrt 2)^2 $

Comment: It is better to use cyllindrical coordinates. But if you do it in cartesian coordinates, $z$ is from $0$ to $2-x^2-y^2$. Your limits are not correct.

Comment: You could instead use that the horizontal slices of the solid are circles with $A=\pi r^2=\pi(2-z)$.

Comment: @user84413 why is it $\pi(2-z)$?

Comment: The circle is given by $x^2+y^2=2-z$, so $r=\sqrt{2-z}$.